# My Angular 8 NPM package is not finding its own assets

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, webpack, node-modules

My assets are being successfully copied over to my scoped npm package; however, when I install my package they are not available after serving the application.

The images within my application are looking for the path like this:
https://localhost:4200/assets/images/image.jpg

In node modules the package folder structure looks like this:

> -scopedPackageName
>
> --bundles
>
> --esm5 ...
>
> --assets
>
> ---images
>
> ----image.jpg   <----- file I want my package to see

Unable to find any good articles about how this works. Any of these would be appreciated.

I have already considered base64 encoding but the loss in quality is unsuitable for my use case.

I've tried a few things in angular.json that did not work:

```
"build": {
                    "builder": ...
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": ...
                        "index": ..
                        "main": ...
                        "polyfill": ...
                        "tsConfig": ...
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/assets/images",
                            {
                                "glob": "**/*",
                                "input": "node_modules/@geode/geode-lib/assets",
                                "output": "/assets/"
                            }
                        ],
                        "styles": [...],
                        "scripts": []
```

AND this

```
"build": {
                    "builder": ...
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": ...
                        "index": ..
                        "main": ...
                        "polyfill": ...
                        "tsConfig": ...
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/assets/images",
                          "node_modules/@geode/geode-lib/assets",
                         "node_modules/@geode/geode-lib/assets/images"
                        ],
                        "styles": [...],
                        "scripts": []
```

The first one doesn't give errors but does not change the outcome.

The second one gives this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: The
>   node_modules/scopedPackageName/assets asset path must start with the
>   project source root. See
>   "C:\Users....\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-MLqnKS\angular-errors.log" for
>   further details.

I've tried moving the assets around in the node modules folder and re-serving the application in hopes that I just put it in the wrong place but have not been successful in finding that place in which the package is looking.

Thanks for any insight that you can provide.

Comment: If you build the application, do you see the `images` somewhere in the `dist` folder?

Comment: Could you please check in the first case if `"input": "./node_modules/@geode/geode-lib/assets"` and `"output": "./assets/"` with `.` at beginning could work?

Comment: @tenkmilan yes the ```images``` are somewhere in the ```dist``` folder just like in the block quote in my comment (sorry it was previously formatted incorrectly).  I've tried moving them too the different levels of the package besides actually outside the package and didn't have any luck.


I also checked all the combinations you suggested for my angular.json file

Comment: @tenkmilan should I post any other info?  it just angular.json involved in pointing to assets right? or does something in the package need to be configured?  How are other packages doing it without configuring things in angular.json?

Comment: No thank you, I understood the question and I posted the answer with an example below. In `angular.json` it is configured, from where should be the assets collected. Those assets will be put while the build process in the `dist` folder and they have to be referenced in the template files accordingly.  The package itself is fine, no further configuration is needed.
Without `angular.json` they are copied with a custom script in the `dist` and referenced in the templates the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I created an example project for this on GitHub, see here: https://github.com/tenkmilan/angular-scoped-package-with-image

In the example there is a scoped package, it is in `@myscope` and the name of the package is `scoped-package`. After `npm install` the example image can be found on `node_modules\@myscope\scoped-package\assets\images` path.

In `angular.json` it is added to the `assets` following way:

```
"assets": [
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "./node_modules/@myscope/scoped-package/assets",
    "output": "/assets/"
  }
```

In `angular.json` this means, that the content of `./node_modules/@myscope/scoped-package/assets` will be placed in the `dist` folder in the `assets` folder. If we run `npm run build` command we can see, that it is really there:

[image]

And this why in the Angular template it has to be referenced following way:

```
<img src="assets/images/doge.jpg">
```